# sort custom arralist by value in android

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have a custom `ArrayList`. This is my `ArrayList`'s model class

```
public class Contact {
private String fullName;
public void setMycontactType(String mycontactType) {
    this.mycontactType = mycontactType;
}

public String getMycontactType() {

    return mycontactType;
}
private String mycontactType;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

private String avatar;

private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar)
{
    this.avatar = avatar;
}
```

}

I inserted some items in my `ArrayList` and some items have `contactType(mycontactType)` different. I mean maybe would be Wallet or Connect or etc. 
now I want to sort my `ArrayList` by `values(contacttype)`. I wrote some code but I can't sort my `array`

```
 Collections.sort(contact_list, new Comparator(){

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Contact p1 = (Contact) o1;
            Contact p2 = (Contact) o2;
            return p1.getMycontactType().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getMycontactType());
        }

    });
```

I would sort my custom `ArrayList` like this. First time I would to see items which has  `contacttype 'Wallet'` and then another contact type's items.
How can I solve my problem?
If anyone can please help me
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you want list of `Contact` in descending order of contact type??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you want `List of Contact in descending order of contact type` field.

For that you can have 2 options :

1. `Comparable`

   ```
   public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

       //.....other code, getters and setters

       @Override
       public int compareTo(Contact c2) {
           return c2.getMycontactType().compareToIgnoreCase(this.getMycontactType());      
       }
   }
   ```

and 2. `Comparator` as you used in code but the small changes is required as below :

```
Collections.sort(contact_list, new Comparator(){
    public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
        return c2.getMycontactType().compareToIgnoreCase(c1.getMycontactType());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(contact_list, new Comparator(){
  public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
    return c1.getMycontactType().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getMycontactType());
  }
});
```

Comment: i tryed it but not working . i want to show first time Wallet contact and then  another contact type

Comment: What is the difference between answer you suggested and code user tried above?

Comment: @Vimal Bera i tryed also Андройд Андройд code  and when i run my arraylist fits element is "Another ContactType''s item

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Collections.sort(contactlist, new Comparator<Contact>(){

         public int compare(Contact p1, Contact p2) {
               return p1.getMycontactType().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getMycontactType());
        }
    });
```